# Mobile APP - API Authentication concept

Tags: android, node.js, api, security, backend

I have a conceptual question and wanted to know if anyone would be kind enough to help.

I will use a simple example to explain my point of view.

I have developed a simple RESTFul API with Node.JS + Express + MongoDB as a backend. The API saves hightscores from an Android game app. I use token-based authentication, where the tokens are generated from a secret and a trusted username/password (hardcoded or not).

But I still have a doubt thinking about safety...

Reverse engineering is a piece of cake since any developer can easily find the backend endpoint of the API and use it with his username and password (or the hardcoded one) to obtain the token.

Then the token ca be used for insert fake highscores via the API.

My questions are:

- Is there any way to avoid this security hole?
- Is using a RESTFull API the correct way to connect a mobile app with a backend in server?
- If not, which is the correct way to develop an APP-Server comunication to save data in a backend DB?.

I think I can ofuscate the code which includes the hardcoded username and password but this dont solve the situation.

PD: Users say that my question is too broad. I made 3 concrete questions and the topic is about avoid the visibility of app information for connect to an API. I know there are too answers, but i dont want a solution, only a way to investigate.

Comment: You can you proguard for your first question. For you 2nd question the answer is yes. Rest API should be implemented.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Then making hard for others to debug by encrypting the secret objects and methods is the best solution. Thanks

Comment: Just don't allow the well-known API user access to update the statistics. Or disallow from the token-based authentication and just allow it using your app. You can probably use scope for that too.

Comment: Patrick, i dont undestand you. I want to allow using the app, but if an user decompile the app he can find the endpoint and the data used for get the token, isnt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no full-proof way to do this. In theory, everything can be debugged - including your verification mechanism (token generation).

Using a web API is a good way to have your mobile app communicate with a backend and works fine in most cases. However, it your case, you basically want to make sure that the API is used only via the Android app you have. This is typically done by encrypting the communication protocol and making it hard for others to debug it. So, your app will encrypt the communication in a way, which is hard to decrypt if you don't know the internals of the app/server. However, this is hard to do from scratch.

If you want a ready-made solution, you could use Google's [Play Game Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/), for highscores, achievements, etc. That should be secure enough, but I can't say what the implications would be for your current situation.

Comment: Thank you very much. The highscore example is to make it simple to understand, but the app is more complex. Then i will ofuscate the code to make it harder to debug.

Comment: @WikiCode keep in mind that major game developers (like Blizzard and Pokemon Go) also have the exact same problems. This is not a trivial thing to do if you want to do it right.

Comment: I know, we must be creative in that sense